# ViewController deinit call clarification

Tags: ios, swift

Expected Behaviour: A view controller should be deallocated when back pressed.

Project: https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit/Example/

```swift
let viewController = BasicExampleViewController()
navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

In `BasicExampleViewController`, I have `deinit{}` that is being called properly.

But when using,

```swift
let viewController = BasicExampleViewController()
let detailViewController = NavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
splitViewController?.showDetailViewController(detailViewController, sender: self)
```

`Deint{}` not called for the same view controller when back pressed.

SplitViewController: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisplitviewcontroller

Is this default behaviour for `SplitViewController` or `ARC` should reclaim memory on back pressed?

Comment: "Deint{} not called"  What is Deint?  `deinit`, you mean?  If so, where do you have it?

Comment: It's like a hook that gets executed when an object is released. ARC determines when we back press our view controller has no reference count and gets deallocated.

Comment: I sort of use it to check I have no memory leak. Reference: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Deinitialization.html